# SharePoint 2013 User profile service doesn't return data for few users from asp.net code

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, asp.net, people-search

I have a SharePoint 2013 deployed in one of the server. AD user can log in to it and view the data.

I have created profile service in SharePoint to sync Active directory users in SharePoint and it is working perfectly fine. I have verified the users in SharePoint people search & it is working as expected. We can view all the users & their attribute correctly in SharePoint.

I have created Asp.net application to show SharePoint users on the web page. Asp.net application communicates to SharePoint using the `clientContext` object.

```
//ASP.net code snippet
var camlQuery = new CamlQuery { 
ViewXml = &lt;View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='UserName'/&gt;&lt;Value Type='Text'&gt;AlexH&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/View&gt;"}
var userInfo = clientContext.Web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(userInfo);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I am extracting first name, last name, department, etc fields from Sharepoint using above code.

I am getting AlexH record in Asp.net code. But if I search his record in SharePoint people search, then I get his profile & attributes with correct values.

If I replace Username AlexH with others (e.g. JaneB, NeilD, etc) then asp.net code returns the attribute values. The only it doesn't return data for AlexH.

Can you please let me know what wrong am I doing here?